# WinRM certificate issue

Tags: certificate, config, winrm

I've made an initial config of winRM using command:

```
winrm -quickconfig
```

Then I configure a listener:

```
winrm set winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS @{Hostname="SOMEHOST.SOMEDOMAIN.DD.COM"; CertificateThumbprint="EFD4C7D3E9CBEA<...>E9E762A5758"}
```

Checking - C:\Windows\system32>winrm enumerate winrm/config/listener

```
Listener
    Address = *
    Transport = HTTP
    Port = 5985
    Hostname
    Enabled = true
    URLPrefix = wsman
    CertificateThumbprint
    ListeningOn = 111.112.66.6, 111.112.66.11, 111.112.66.12, 127.0.0.1, ::1

Listener
    Address = *
    Transport = HTTPS
    Port = 5986
    Hostname = SOMEHOST.SOMEDOMAIN.DD.COM
    Enabled = true
    URLPrefix = wsman
    CertificateThumbprint = EFD4C7D3E9CBEA<...>E9E762A5758
    ListeningOn = 111.112.66.6, 111.112.66.11, 111.112.66.12, 127.0.0.1, ::1
```

The listener takes the correct certificate. The problem is that when I run quickconfig, it takes a different certificate for winrm config ( 13 f8 46 d6 <...> 6c62 2f 5e 17 ) and Azure DevOps builder cannot connect to this machine with pssession. And in build I see following error:

```
Connecting to remote server SOMEHOST.SOMEDOMAIN.DD.COM failed with the following error message : The WinRM client received an HTTP server error status (500)
```

And in SOMEHOST's logs I see following error:

```
A fatal error occurred when attempting to access the SSL server credential private key. The error code returned from the cryptographic module is 0x8009030D. The internal error state is 10001.
```

WinRM config:

```
C:\Windows\system32>winrm get winrm/config
Config
    MaxEnvelopeSizekb = 8192
    MaxTimeoutms = 60000
    MaxBatchItems = 32000
    MaxProviderRequests = 4294967295
    Client
        NetworkDelayms = 5000
        URLPrefix = wsman
        AllowUnencrypted = false
        Auth
            Basic = true
            Digest = true
            Kerberos = true
            Negotiate = true
            Certificate = true
            CredSSP = false
        DefaultPorts
            HTTP = 5985
            HTTPS = 5986
        TrustedHosts
    Service
        RootSDDL = O:NSG:BAD:P(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GR;;;IU)S:P(AU;FA;GA;;;WD)(AU;SA;GXGW;;;WD)
        MaxConcurrentOperations = 4294967295
        MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser = 1500
        EnumerationTimeoutms = 240000
        MaxConnections = 300
        MaxPacketRetrievalTimeSeconds = 120
        AllowUnencrypted = false
        Auth
            Basic = true
            Kerberos = true
            Negotiate = true
            Certificate = false
            CredSSP = true
            CbtHardeningLevel = Relaxed
        DefaultPorts
            HTTP = 5985
            HTTPS = 5986
        IPv4Filter = *
        IPv6Filter = *
        EnableCompatibilityHttpListener = false
        EnableCompatibilityHttpsListener = false
        CertificateThumbprint = 13 f8 46 d6 <...> 6c62 2f 5e 17
        AllowRemoteAccess = true
    Winrs
        AllowRemoteShellAccess = true
        IdleTimeout = 7200000
        MaxConcurrentUsers = 2147483647
        MaxShellRunTime = 2147483647
        MaxProcessesPerShell = 2147483647
        MaxMemoryPerShellMB = 2147483647
        MaxShellsPerUser = 2147483647
```

How to configure WinRM config and listener with the same certificate? I have a command to do this with a listener but was unable to find the same for WinRM config.